# Image size changing dynamically via URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, gd

I have a folder named `images`, where I have images like: hero.jpg, hero_medium.jpg, hero_small.jpg. My question is, if this is the correct solution, or maybe it would be better to have one big picture and change its size via URL. At the moment I have managed to do something like this in `img.php` file in `images` folder:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$filename = 'hero.jpg';

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

if(empty($_GET['w'])){
    $width = $width_orig;
} else {
    $width = $_GET['w'];
}
$height=$width;

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

I would like to change the size of a photo by a friendly URL, i.e. hero_medium.jpg to e.g. 768px in php using htaccess, is such a thing possible?

EDIT: Apple has an interesting situation on its website. The URL for the images looks like the following: `https://www.apple.com/newsroom/images/environments/stores/Apple_Tower-Theatre-now-open-in-downtown-LA-store-interior-wide-shot_062421_big.jpg.medium.jpg`, why is there `big.jpg.medium.jpg`? I suspect they may be doing something with htaccess file, because having that many photos it would be unreadable, so I think they are resizing them dynamically. What do you think?

EDIT 2: I noticed that it takes much longer to load and change the image via php, is this actually a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the width and height of an image using URL parameters. This can be useful for resizing images dynamically. To achieve this, you can append the width and height parameters to the image URL. Here's an example of how to do that

Original Image URL: `https://example.com/image.jpg`

Resize Image with URL: `https://example.com/image.jpg?width=600&height=400`

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Image Resizing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="resize.php?width=600&height=400" alt="Resized Image">
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file name with 'resize.php'

```
// Get the image file path (replace with your image's actual path)
$imagePath = 'image.png';

// Get the requested width and height from the URL parameters
$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? intval($_GET['width']) : null;
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? intval($_GET['height']) : null;

// Check if both width and height are provided and are valid integers
if ($width && $height && is_numeric($width) && is_numeric($height)) {
    // Load the original image
    $originalImage = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath);

    // Create a new image with the specified width and height
    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    // Resize the original image to the new dimensions
    imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($originalImage), imagesy($originalImage));

    // Output the resized image as a JPEG
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagepng($resizedImage);

    // Clean up resources
    imagedestroy($originalImage);
    imagedestroy($resizedImage);
} else {
    // Handle the case where width and height parameters are missing or invalid
    echo 'Invalid parameters';
}
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to return an image of adequate dimensions, there are several ways to achieve this.

Maybe you want to have a look at this:
https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-to-the-responsive-images-syntax-in-html/

Comment: This is a great thing, but my question is how to add these images there, whether to have several versions or to scale them dynamically. I think you may have misunderstood my question.